# Is it possible to dry-run install a CPAN bundle?

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm migrating from one server to another and using `perl -MCPAN -eautobundle` to work out which modules I should be bringing along.

Some modules are a bit problematic at install-time though (mainly due to relying on non-perl libraries etc), and it would be good to be able to see a list of the modules that it wants to install/update, rather than doing a full install of the bundle and looking at large slabs of test output etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing CPAN installs, I recommend using the `cpanm` tool rather than the CPAN module directly.  `cpanm` has a `--scandeps` option which will tell you which modules will be installed to satisfy the dependencies of the module you're trying to install, which sounds like exactly you're use-case.

Reference: [`cpanm` perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.6002/bin/cpanm)